# Iterate through 2D List, assign each value on a row in the list to a variable, repeat for each row - python

Tags: python, list, loops, 2d

I have a list comprising a number of X,Y values

```
aList = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6],[7, 8]]
```

i.e. X = 1, Y = 2

I need to extract each X and Y value on a row separately, assign those values to an X and Y variable respectively, and then act on the X and Y values.

This should then loop to the next row where the same process would occur again. I'll use print instead of the excessive code that needs to occur after this loop.

i.e. loop starts, X is assigned 1, Y is assigned 2, X and Y are used as inputs in formula, loop ends (and repeat for the remaining values in this list)

```
aListLen = len(aList)
aListRows = len(aList)
aListCols = len(aList[0])
```

The following code only extracts values 1 by one in the list

```
for row in range(aListRows):
    for column in range(aListCols):
        X = aList[row][column]
        print X
```

adding a Y variable as follows results in an error

```
for row in range(aListRows):
    for column in range(aListCols):
        X = a[row][column]
        Y = a[row][column+1]
        print X
        print Y
```

Looking at it now, I'm not sure the following if/elif loop would work as the X and Y values need to go in a formula together. 
<strike>I could add an if/elif statement under the 2nd loop, but I'd still need to have a way of forcing the 2nd loop to repeat. (Which brings us back to the original problem anyway)</strike>

```
for row in range(aListRows):
    for column in range(aListCols):
        if column == 0:
            X = aList[row][column] 
        elif column == 1:
            Y = aList[row][column]
```

How can I force the loop to restart once the X value has been provided?
I assume the loop would then repeat, this time providing the value for Y.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Should point out this is Python 2.7 (so I cannot use anything exclusive to Python 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign the variables instead of printing them you could do:

```
for X,Y in aList:
   tempX = X
   tempY = Y
```

At the first iteration tempX will have a value of 1, tempY will have a value of 2. At the second iteration tempX will be 3, tempY will be 4...

Answer (score 3):

You're looping over the indices of the inner list and adding 1 to them. This will cause an `IndexError` when `column` contains the value of `aListCols`, since `len(a[row]) == column+1`

I think you are looking for this:

```
In [17]: aList = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6],[7, 8]]

In [18]: for X,Y in aList:
   ....:     print "X value is %s, Y value is %s" %(X, Y)
   ....:     
X value is 1, Y value is 2
X value is 3, Y value is 4
X value is 5, Y value is 6
X value is 7, Y value is 8
```

Comment: I need to assign X = 1 and Y = 2, so that the X and Y variables can be used in a formula. Print was just used as an example of what occurs after they are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of a loop, use a recursive function.
Basically, that is a function that calls itself. For example:

```
def myfunction():
    (something happens that wants you to start the function over)
    myfunction()
```

Hence, it will call the function again, forcing the code to go back to the top.